# How to uninstall ubuntu in a dual boot system?

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot

I want to uninstall ubuntu OS 16.10 from my system and assign its partition back to windows. How can i do it? I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: This is a great tutorial for it. http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-in-windows-dual-boot-environment/

Comment: Also from Ubuntu there is a How-To: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader

Answer (score 2):

It's really simple.
Just remove Linux partitions using `Disk Management` and run following commands as administrator in `CMD`

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
```

Then you can create new partition from unallocated space or extend existing partition with it.

I would recommend running this too

```
sfc /scannow
```

**EDIT:**

As said in comments, this answer only helps if you have Windows installation disc/cd. If you dont, you can start live ubuntu cd and do this
**Method 2**

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
```

> Boot-Repair lets you fix these issues with a simple click, which
>   (generally reinstalls GRUB and) restores access to the operating
>   systems you had installed before the issue.

Also, You may download the [Boot-repair Disk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) **iso images** and burn it to a USB stick. Then, boot the stick and repair the MBR on the defected hard disk as you like. Both 32-bit and 64-bit versions are available.

[image]

**Method 3**.. also requires ubuntu live cd/usb

```
sudo apt-get install mbr
sudo install-mbr -i n -p D -t 0 /dev/sda
```

**Method 4**.. also requires ubuntu live cd/usb

```
sudo apt-get install syslinux
sudo dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr.bin of=/dev/sda
```

Please change `/dev/sda` to your disk for Method 3 and 4

Comment: BootRec.exe is not officially available for download so without the Windows ISO or CD this answer won't help.

Comment: He can also use Linux live cd to fix grub on disk :)

Comment: He want's partition back to windows, I might be wrong but can the Linux live cd create a windows boot partition? I thought only Windows could do that.

Comment: You can use linux to fix grub on disk where Windows is installed without a problem. Been there done that

Comment: I don't think this is possible without a Windows CD: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader